# importing error default_collate is not defined

Tags: python, pytorch

I tried to import `default_collate` from `torch.utils.data.dataloader` but it says that `default_collate` does not exist, but another function does exist (`_collate_fn_t`).

```
from torch.utils.data.dataloader import default_collate
from torch.utils.data.dataloader import _collate_fn_t
```

Are these commands are similar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `_collate_fn_t` is the type definition of a collate function in general, it is defined [here](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/c371542efc31b1abfe6f388042aa3ab0cef935f2/torch/utils/data/dataloader.py#L31) as:

```
_collate_fn_t = Callable[[List[T]], Any]
```

`default_collate` is the default collate function used by the DataLoader class.

Importing these is not equivalent, you should check your spelling and try again with:

```
from torch.utils.data.dataloader import default_collate
```